# What edge/corner case am I missing with this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, date, join, sql-order-by

[This](https://leetcode.com/problems/rising-temperature/) leetcode sql question was giving me problems earlier today. The question is as follows:

```
Table: Weather

+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| id            | int     |
| recordDate    | date    |
| temperature   | int     |
+---------------+---------+
id is the column with unique values for this table.
This table contains information about the temperature on a certain day.

 

Write a solution to find all dates' Id with higher temperatures compared to its previous dates (yesterday).

Return the result table in any order.

The result format is in the following example.
```

I have now solved it using a leftjoin and some where clauses, but my initial approach was:

```
SELECT w.id As id
FROM 
(
  SELECT id, recordDate, temperature, LAG(temperature) OVER() as prev_temp, recordDate - LAG(recordDate) OVER() as day_diff
  FROM Weather
  ORDER BY recordDate ASC
) w
WHERE w.temperature > w.prev_temp AND day_diff = 1
```

This passes all except the final testcase (too large to post here, please refer to the link)

This is my final solution that works:

```
Select w1.id as id
FROM Weather AS w1
LEFT JOIN Weather w2 ON DATEDIFF(w1.recordDate, w2.recordDate) = 1
WHERE w1.temperature > w2.temperature
```

Could anyone identify why my initial solution doesn't pass?
Furthermore, if anyone has a process for debugging SQL queries, I'd really appreciate some pointers

Comment: The question will be worthless if the URL you gave is broken ! Please edit your question and [add Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @SelVazi Sorry, link is fixed. I would provide a minimal example, but I can't figure out where the test case is failing, hopefully the URL is enough.